# Why am I seeing tag warnings while editing?

Tags: bug, edits, tag-warnings

Tag warnings (or "tag tips") are yellow warning boxes that pop up whenever you go to ask a question with a certain tag (e.g. [regex] or [sql] on Stack Overflow). See the [feature request that caused this to be implemented here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274632/6083675).

The problem is, tag warnings show up if you're **editing** (sometimes, such as when clicking on "edit tags"):

> [image: An image showing the bug happening]

It makes no sense to trigger tag warnings during an edit, especially when it's someone else's post. Tag warnings are specifically designed to give advice to the asker, so there's no advice there that an editor who isn't also the OP would be able to act on (usually).

Alternatively, it makes no sense to trigger them so inconsistently when editing. If you did have advice for editors in there, most would never see it.

Here are some questions with tag tips:

- [Why doesn't [01-12] range work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3148240/6083675)
- [How can I automatically determine fonts used in an image or PDF?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/374/79217)

Comment: I don't think tag warnings are exclusively used to give guidance to the asker, so I don't think this is necessarily a bug. Tag warnings often specify when the tag should and shouldn't be used – and people other than the asker can edit the tags of the post, so it seems like it's correct that that guidance is shown to them.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov When I wrote this question, I apparently had a foolproof method to trigger it when editing (remove the title). However, it's no longer working like that for me either. I still do trigger it when editing (as a moderator!) but I don't have any specifics other than "mess around with the tags or something".

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: Hmm... It looks like the tag warning does appear when I hit "Edit tags" on a question on RPG.SE and add the `dungeons-and-dragons` tag, then move my mouse focus away from the tag editing area... But it seems like you're right – for whatever reason, I'm not seeing the tag warning when I click the "Edit" button below the post to edit the post as a whole while I'm logged in to this account, or when suggesting an edit in an incognito window. May be worth reporting as a separate bug if it hasn't been reported already.

Answer (score 10):

From the comments:

> I apparently had a foolproof method to trigger it when editing (remove the title). However, it's no longer working like that for me either.

My foolproof method to trigger the warning is to use the inline tag editor. That works every time.

Speaking of that, it has always bugged me that the warning is *more* in-your-face for editors (particularly those who have **10K+** rep and are using the inline tag editor) compared to how it's displayed to the asker.

This is what someone who has 10K+ rep and is expected to have decent experience with the site would see:

[image: Tag warning in inline tag editor]

The warning is displayed as soon as the tags field loses focus; It's very prominent and cannot be easily overlooked. Now, compare that to what the asker sees:

[image: Tag warning in asker's view]

The warning is only triggered after clicking <kbd>Review your question</kbd>; it's displayed on the right sidebar, far from the location of the mouse cursor (and probably the author's field of view) at that moment. I believe that most users will overlook it. Not to mention that many users probably just click <kbd>Post your question</kbd> right away and don't spend time reviewing what they've written, let alone noticing the warning displayed on the sidebar.

I would think it's a better idea to display the warning to the asker in the same way that's being done with the inline tag editor. Even better, display the warning as soon as the tag is selected and don't wait until the field loses focus. Aaaand it would be nice if the warning isn't displayed in the inline tag editor because it's being used by the (hopefully) experienced users of the site.